# Disable resizing in Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, resize

How to disable resizing the browser in Silverlight application

Answer (score 1):

You can't and nor should you be able to.  The browser is an application that belongs to the user, it is not something that your application should allowed to take charge of.

If you want to prevent the resizing of your Silverlight content then specify a fixed width and height for the `<object>` tag in the html hosting the Silverlight plugin.